# Debugging Tide Applications

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, tidesdk

Looking forward to the TideSDK 1.3 release. I've extended the sample app provided but I'm unable to figure out how to breakpoint my code and step through it for debugging purposes. Of course when running in the browser I can use chrome debugging tools but in the Tide sandbox how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to open up the inspector inside the app and use the webkit inspector to breakpoint and step through your source code.

Comment: Note: this only enables you to debug the client side code but not your native application code.